# The StackOverFlowError commons-dbcp2 rollback

Tags: java, hibernate, database-connection, apache-commons-dbcp, apache-commons-io

Suddenly in one of the environment we see the below repeated lines of dbcp2 and eventually the StackOverFlowError.

The Hibernate (3.6.10) getHibernateSession().getTransaction().rollback() is called in our code.
It uses commons-dbcp2(2.6.0). The jdbcdriver is ojdbc8-12.2.0.1, Oracle 12C, and Java is 1.8.

The below lines repeat for more than 3000 times. I suspect some bug in dbcp2? why does it loops in own methods. If anyone of you have come across similar issue kindly share. Thinking to update the dependencies to latest for hibernate, commons-dbcp2 and commons-io.

---

```
            at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.toStringAppendFields(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1605)
            at org.apache.commons.pool2.BaseObject.toString(BaseObject.java:31)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingConnection.toString(PoolingConnection.java:606)
            at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3408)
            at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:516)
            at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.toStringAppendFields(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1605)
            at org.apache.commons.pool2.BaseObject.toString(BaseObject.java:31)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingConnection.toString(PoolingConnection.java:606)
            at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3408)
            at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:516)
            at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.toStringAppendFields(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1605)
```

[Updated:20210818] The code snippet which we use to rollback, as sample is below:

```
this.getHibernateSession().getTransaction().rollback();
this.getHibernateSession().clear();
this.getHibernateSession().getTransaction().begin();
```

Comment: Could you please share your code? Connection as a parameter to StringBuffer append function is not an expected pattern I think....

Comment: To give an idea, the place from where we do the rollback using the hibernate session,  I have written the sample code and updated in the post. The exact code I cannot share because of the policy.

Comment: Assuming that dbcp uses commons-pool2-2.6.0-sources.jar, it seems that the driver tries to convert the  KeyedPooledObjectFactory to string then tries to convert  KeyedObjectPool to string which possibly causes the loop.  It may be helpful if you share your DB config...

Comment: We have upgraded the Oracle database from 12C to 19C and it stopped giving problem. Though not able to investigate further but now this looks got resolved.

Comment: Am getting exactly the same error. Not using Hibernate, but am performing a rollback(). We are using DBCP2 version 2.9.0 and SQL Server.